# Since clause and present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, sentence-choice

I have to correct the sentence: *I haven't seen Peter since he begins seeing his new girlfriend.* 
The correct answer is: *I haven't seen Peter since he began seeing his new girlfriend*.
I thought I could use the present perfect in the since clause because is a fact that initiates in the past and continues in the present.

> Could I use "I haven't seen Peter since he has begun seeing his new girlfriend" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the **present perfect tense** with time expressions, which place the action at a definite time in the past.

> I haven't seen Peter since he **began** seeing his new girlfriend.

The **beginning** of the relationship happened at a certain time in the past and not over a period of time.

> I haven't seen Peter since he **has been** dating XY.

Here you are describing a **duration**. - They started dating at some time in the past and  are still dating now.